# How to use batchWriteItem to write more than 25 items into DynamoDB Table using PHP

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS SDK for PHP 3.x

A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.

```
  $result = $dynamodbClient->batchWriteItem([
  'RequestItems' => [
    $tableName => [
      [
        'PutRequest' => [
          'Item' => [
            'Id' => ['N' => '1'],
            'AlbumTitle' => [
              'S' => 'Somewhat Famous',
            ],
            'Artist' => [
              'S' => 'No One You Know',
            ],
            'SongTitle' => [
              'S' => 'Call Me Today',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],          
    ],
  ],
]);
```

For single item its working fine. How can I write more than 25 items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write more than 25 items, you have to repeatedly call BatchWriteItem, adding items from your collection, 25 at a time.

Something along these lines (pseudo-code):

```
requests = []; // use an array to stage your put item requests
foreach(item in SourceCollection) {
    addItem(item, requests); // add this item to the array 
    if(count(requests) == 25) { // when you have 25 ready..
       // result = dynamodbClient->batchWriteItem(...)
       requests = []; // clean up the array of put item requests
       // handle the failed items from the result object
    }
}
// handle any remaining requests
while (len(requests) > 0) {
   // result = dynamodbClient->batchWriteItem(...)
   requests = []
   // handle any failed requests, either by re-adding them
   // back into the requests array, or doing something else with them
   // NOTE: if retrying, need to decide when to give up
}
```

Make sure to handle failed items from each batchWriteItem result by re-adding them back to the requests

Comment: How to hadle failed items from each batchWriteItem result

Comment: You can retry them. Just add them all back into the requests array

Comment: I tried each 25 item per batch. I needs to add 2000 items to a table. Each batch return 75 capacity units. But only 270 items added to my table, and also result return some unprocessed item. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: If the total number of items is not divisible by 25 not all items will be written. Let's say you have 60 items. The last 10 items (the remainder) won't be written because the condition `count(requests) == 25` will never be met.

Comment: good catch -- fixed and added some comments to clarify

Answer (score 2):

Here is my way for a lambda function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.REGION })

  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  const {data, table, cb} = JSON.parse(event.body);

  console.log('{data, table, cb}:', {data, table, cb});

  // Build the batches
  var batches = [];
  var current_batch = [];
  var item_count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Add the item to the current batch
    item_count++
    current_batch.push({
      PutRequest: {
        Item: data[i],
      },
    })
    // If we've added 25 items, add the current batch to the batches array
    // and reset it
    if (item_count % 25 === 0) {
      batches.push(current_batch)
      current_batch = []
    }
  }

  // Add the last batch if it has records and is not equal to 25
  if (current_batch.length > 0 && current_batch.length !== 25) {
    batches.push(current_batch)
  }

  // Handler for the database operations
  var completed_requests = 0
  var errors = false

  function requestHandler (request) {

    console.log('in the handler: ', request)

    return function (err, data) {
      // Increment the completed requests
      completed_requests++;

      // Set the errors flag
      errors = (errors) ? true : err;

      // Log the error if we got one
      if(err) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        console.error("Request that caused database error:");
        console.error(JSON.stringify(request, null, 2));
        callback(err);
      }else {
        var response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          isBase64Encoded: false
        };
        console.log(`success: returned ${data}`);
        callback(null, response);
      }

      // Make the callback if we've completed all the requests
      if(completed_requests === batches.length) {
        cb(errors);
      }
    }
  }

  // Make the requests
  var params;
  for (var j = 0; j < batches.length; j++) {
    // Items go in params.RequestItems.id array
    // Format for the items is {PutRequest: {Item: ITEM_OBJECT}}
    params = '{"RequestItems": {"' + table + '": []}}'
    params = JSON.parse(params)
    params.RequestItems[table] = batches[j]

    console.log('before db.batchWrite: ', params)

    // Perform the batchWrite operation
    docClient.batchWrite(params, requestHandler(params))
  }
};


dealspoondBatchWrite
```

Comment: Like this approach @gildiny  Just one question.  I am tiring to get thi s to write to a DynamoDB local image.  Any idea how to set the DB endpoint?  I looked thru the docs and couldn't find an api to do this.

Comment: @RyanCarville This is how I used it in my React component:

`const apiName = "api_name";
        const apiEndpoint = "/add-batch";

        try {
            await API.post(apiName, apiEndpoint, {body: {data: <your_data>, table: 'table_name', cb: null}});
} catch (error) {
            console.log('ERROR: ', error)
        }
`

Comment: Thanks @gildiny.  I ended up making this work.
`var { DynamoDB } = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: 'localhost',
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',
});`

Answer (score 0):

i am using the following code to add data using batchWriteItem.  Suggest if there is a better way.

```
    // Build the batches
$albums= "// collection of album json";
$batches = [];
$current_batch = [];
$item_count = 0;
foreach ($albums as $album) {
    // Add the item to the current batch
    $item_count++;
    $json = json_encode($album);
    $data['PutRequest'] = array('Item' => $marshaler->marshalJson($json));
    array_push($current_batch, $data);
    // If we've added 25 items, add the current batch to the batches array
    // and reset it
    if ($item_count % 25 == 0) {
        array_push($batches, $current_batch);
        $current_batch = [];
    }
}
// Handler for the database operations
// Add the last batch if it has records and is not equal to 25
if (count($current_batch) > 0 && count($current_batch) != 25) {
    array_push($batches, array_values($current_batch));
}
//batches.push(current_batch);
// Handler for the database operations
$completed_requests = 0;
$errors = false;
$batch_count = 0;
foreach ($batches as $batch) {
    try {
        $batch_count++;
        $params = array('RequestItems' => array($tableName => $batch), 'ReturnConsumedCapacity' => 'TOTAL', 'ReturnItemCollectionMetrics' => 'SIZE');
        $response = $dynamodb->batchWriteItem($params);
        echo "Album $batch_count Added." . "<br>";
        echo "<pre>";
//        print_r($params);
        print_r($response);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
        echo "Unable to add movie:\n";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
//    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the two arrays `$batches` and `$current_batch`. Just use one array. And, as the array fills (ie. `if count($current_batch) == 25`) perform the write. After the write, you have to look through the `$response` and remove all items successfully written from `$current_batch`, keeping any that failed. This way, you keep retrying the failed ones.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is to change your code from pre-filling a batch of batches, into a single "fill-and-write" method. Keep adding items to the batch up to 25. Try to write them. Inspect results and remove any items that succeeded from the batch, leaving any that failed. Keep adding new items until you've added them all..

Comment: Also, if writing 25 items takes 75 capacity units it means that your items are fairly large. Make sure your table has enough capacity provisioned (ie. at least 75 WCU)

Comment: @MikeDinescu how do you know which items in a batch has failed?

Comment: The response would include a list of failed items

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a very convenient array function to do that called [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```php
$items = [
    'PutRequest' => [
        'Item' => [
            'Id' => ['N' => '1'],
            'AlbumTitle' => [
                'S' => 'Somewhat Famous',
            ],
            'Artist' => [
                'S' => 'No One You Know',
            ],
            'SongTitle' => [
                'S' => 'Call Me Today',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

foreach (array_chunk($items, 25) as $chunk) {
    try {
        $response = $dynamoDbClient->batchWriteItem([
            'RequestItems' => [
                $tableName => $chunk
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Log the exception and handle it
    }
}
```

Make sure you define the two variables `$dynamoDbClient` and `$tableName` somewhere before the `foreach` loop.